# LifeRay alternative in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, opencms

I have explored some of the features of LifeRay from past few months. But due to high on hardware and development resource I would not want to go with LifeRay. Is there any good alternative to liferay in asp.net c#. I have seen following CMS application similar to LifeRay. Just want to know if someone has used it.

1. AxCMS.Net
2. Umbraco CMS
3. DotNetNuke

Thanks,
Piyush

Answer (score 1):

We've been throwing around a few of those terms in our office and nearly settled for Umbraco. I think we were satisfied with it but in the end decided to go towards Drupal because of it's wider user-base and support.

Comment: I too had seen Drupal but the expertise we have are in .net only so thinking on the same. Thanks !